# Is it possible to save log of Ruby on Rails delayed job log in terminal output, instead of in delayed_job.log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Currently the application that I'm working on is using Ruby on Rails. The application use `delayed_job.log` file to log the delayed job activity. However, the application is hosted in Openshift environment, using pod, and if the pod is deleted, and if a new pod is created, the application will make a new `delayed_job.log` file. One of the proposed solution from an engineer in the company is to write the log in terminal output. How can I do that? The goal is to save the information that written in `delayed_job.log` file to terminal output, so that I can see the log in the future, I can check the log, even the log from the deleted pod, using Kibana, instead of `delayed_job.log` file. Any help is appreciated.

Update :

We tried to put `Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger` in `delayed_job_config.rb` but still did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can change the logger in `config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb` to something like:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Comment: We already tried that, but it still does not work

Comment: You need to restart the app after this change, did you do that? do you see any error?

Comment: Yes we already restart the app

Comment: And also, we did not see any error